# Using XMPP with iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, xmpp

I am looking for an ebook or online tutorial for building a chat application iphone sdk / XMPP server. I am currently using the xmppframework.

Any guide or any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The xmppframework has a tutorial for iPhone: https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS

Comment: Thanks David :) , i have been through it, all done got it connected to my XMPP server, but now i am trying to send/receive messages.. i have been looking for an example.. Any help?

Many Thanks :) :)

Comment: i have been through the "servelessdemo" project , it uses bonjour networking for peer to peer communication. Although i havenot tried the peer to peer example, but there seems to be a complete working example ChatViewCOntroller, where it listens to incoming/outgoing messages. I have been trying to be able to connect to my XMPP server instead of using the peer to peer.You have any idea David how this can be achieved :)

Thanks :)