# How to integrate XMPP framework for iPhone?

Tags: ios, xmpp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement XMPP protocol in objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358244/how-to-implement-xmpp-protocol-in-objective-c)

I am a new developer for Xcode, I don't know how to use XMPP Framework to develop chat application for iPhone.
So, please can help me for creating chat appication using XMPP? 
Also provide some example, if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: See also [How to implement XMPP protocol in objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358244/how-to-implement-xmpp-protocol-in-objective-c) and [Using XMPP with iPhone SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639012/using-xmpp-with-iphone-sdk)

Comment: //*****Best Way create podfile with This info:

platform :ios, '8.0'

use_frameworks!

pod 'XMPPFramework', :git => "https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework.git", :branch => 'master'

pod 'CocoaAsyncSocket'

pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'

pod 'KissXML/SwiftNSXML'

Answer (score 8):

[Tutsplus](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/series/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios/) recently posted extensive tutorial on creating chat application using xmpp framework.

Comment: Just looking for this...Thanks for the post link... Its very helpful

Comment: You can learn step by step XMPP Framework setup by following link:

http://goaheadwithiphonetech.blogspot.in/2014/05/chatting-app-xmpp-framework_21.html